# I'm looking for secure Linux kiosk software

Tags: linux

We have an unattended kiosk at a local sports arena that currently runs a hardened Linux distribution from a CD-ROM ISO. The project that produced the distribution is no longer active -- in fact, it disappeared from the internet.

**What I'm looking for is a Linux kiosk distribution which:**

1. Boots from CD (no hard drive installation)
2. Only runs a web browser
3. Restarts the web browser automatically when closed (or after a time-out period)
4. Does not allow any keyboard shortcuts (to open a terminal, etc...)
5. Can survive the Kiosk Attack Tools (http://ikat.ha.cked.net)

I know that there are lots of Google results for this sort of thing, and if I had the time, I would follow one of the myriad guides to "roll my own"... but I just don't have the time.

Can any of you recommend a distribution ***that you have personally used*** to fulfill this need?

Comment: Please recommend only distributions that you have personally used which you know fulfill the requirements.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing - except that I'd like to install it to a hard drive for better performance, while still retaining the read-only advantages of the CD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need "gdm" with auto-login and ctrl-alt-backspace disabled.

Choose "matchbox" as a window-manager: it was designed for kiosk use. It's capable of maximizing windows to fullscreen (while dialogs still look nice). It also consumes little resources, and has an on-screen keyboard.

Use "xautolock" to reset browser on inactivity period.

If you're still looking for a distribution, try [WebConverger](http://webconverger.com/). I saw it in action: a really nice pick! Alas, is shareware :(

Comment: Thanks Tync!  This is the distribution that I chose for the project, though I chose it late last week.

For anyone who needs an out-of-the-box bootable CDROM kiosk, WebConverger is easy to use, and (as of this posting) immune to the kiosk attack tools.

Even though WebConverger has a commercial solution, and I highly recommend it if you need commercial support, the basic model is freeware.

Answer (score 3):

**Linux Kiosk Appliance**

The Linux Kiosk Appliance comes to mind...

https://launchpad.net/kiosk

Looks like the project might be dead though... Hmmmm... Here's a place to download it...

http://www.rpath.org/project/kiosk

I'd be inclined to download the LiveCD and give it a try.  Its been a looooong time since I last looked at it but I seem to recall it working just fine when I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

http://www.imedialinux.com/kiosk_appliances

Comment: Interesting link... have you tried that one?  Is it complete or a "roll your own" type of development platform?  I wasn't able to tell (for sure) by looking at it.

Comment: This is a kiosk development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this: http://www2.userful.com/products/userful-desktop

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a web browser, you don't actually need a window manager at all. Just put the browser of your choice to *~/.xinitrc* file and you're all set.

An example of *~/.xinitrc* file:

`mozilla-firefox &`