# PXE bootable browser

Tags: boot, pxe-boot

I would like to have a system that boots using PXE and only runs a single application: A graphical webbrowser with a hardcoded homepage that loads upon opening.

I could use the Knoppix Terminal server and strip this thing down to only the webbrowser. 
However I figured someone here may know of something that is a lot less work to make than manually stripping down knoppix.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a kiosk system. There are a lot of good suggestions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/59329/im-looking-for-secure-linux-kiosk-software)

Answer (score 0):

[xPUD](http://www.xpud.org/) is an excellent choice for setting up a slim OS with just the browser. Give it a shot I am sure you will love it.

Comment: Great suggestion. I booted the ISO in VMware and it looks nice. I tried to boot it over PXE ( I found this http://vimeo.com/8613977 ) and I get a lot of errors (i.e. it won't boot). Any suggestions?

Comment: My car doesn't work, any suggestions?  ;)  You need to provide more details for people to assist you--specifically any error messages you might be receiving.

Answer (score 0):

After generating a livecd for Debian or, even Gentoo Linux, use iPXE to bootstrap the iso via HTTP.